# Posting to user's facebook news feed without posting to his wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm tring to send customized news to my users via Facebook.

I've tried posting private posts to their walls, so they show up on their news feed, but people got upset by the new posts on their wall (even though noone else can see them)
Is there a way to do this?

I considered building a page per user and suggest to the user to follow it - can this be done via API?
Can a user follow updates on just any page (non fan page) that he Liked, or that has a FB comments box?

Alternatively, can I programatically send Facebook notifications?

Comment: Has this changed with the new news feed items facebook just launched?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a single Page for your app.  Then when a user connects with your app, auto-follow that page so that all posts to that page show up in the user's feed.

Now just add new posts to that Page with privacy settings targetted at just that user.

Thats my off the cuff answer.

Comment: If you do this you'll probably want to manage the number of posts on your page so you don't end up with several billion posts on it.  You could delete all posts older than a month or something every so often.

Comment: Sounds promising. But does it scale well? Can i give permissions to thousands of users for an item ?

Comment: After taking a closer look this may not work:
In the UI there's no way to specify privacy (only targeting, e.g. geo).
When trying through the graph API the result is:
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#100) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include privacy."}}